# Is there a difference between jQuery recursive function calls and Javascript's setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, jquery-animate, setinterval

I am animating a few images of waves to go up and down slowly and repeatedly to give it a more lively feel and I found Javascript's setInterval().  This is working perfectly to animate my different wave images up and down every 5.3 seconds (at slightly different speeds).

```
self.setInterval("waves()",5300);

function waves() {  
$('.waves1').animate({
    bottom: '-5px'
}, 2000);
$('.waves1').animate({
    bottom: '7px'
}, 3000);

$('.waves2').animate({
    bottom: '-5px'
}, 2200);
$('.waves2').animate({
    bottom: '7px'
}, 2800);

$('.waves3').animate({
    bottom: '-5px'
}, 1800);
$('.waves3').animate({
    bottom: '7px'
}, 3200);
}
```

After implementing this, I also found that you could just use a recursive jQuery function to keep the animation going also.  For example:

```
function animateWaves() {
   $('.waves1').animate({ top: '+=15' },
                        { duration: 2000, easing: "linear" })
               .animate({ top: '-=15' },
                        { duration: 3000, easing: "linear",
                          complete: animateWaves });
}

$(function() {
    animateWaves();
});
```

What are the advantages of one (recursion or setInterval) over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really recursion.  It's a self-reference from within the function, but it's **just** a reference, and not a function call.  The function call is made later by the framework when the animation completes.

Recursion involves a "stack" of active function invocations, one on top of another. (There can be intervening active functions in the case of intertwined mutually-recursive functions.)  That's not the case here.  By the time the call is made based on the reference passed to the `.animate()` call, the outer call to "animateWaves" will have completed.

Note that the jQuery animation mechanism also uses, underneath it all, the browser's timer mechanisms.  If you're using the library anyway, you're probably better off letting it handle the repetition for you.

Comment: No, it's not making a call to itself. It's passing a reference to itself to jQuery and asking that jQuery call it **later**.

Comment: Oh, and I was not explicit enough I guess - I'd say the second way is better, because you can be *sure* that the animation will be complete at the time the function is invoked again.

Comment: And that's because the setInterval has no callback at all with the function - if there's a delay in the animation it will still restart after 5.3 seconds, right?

Comment: Yes exactly - when you set up your own, separate timer to "intercept" the end of the animation, there's a risk it'll be a little too soon or a little too late.